# Knowing if code was compiled for iPhone, iPad or Universal

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

Is there a way to know at run time if the app running was compiled for iPhone only, iPad only or is universal?

I ask this because there is this box you check when you compile, where you can select iphone, ipad, universal. If this box exists, something in the binary will be different, so in theory, that can be checked.

[image]

Unfortunately I have no code to show because I don't even know how/where to start.

Comment: Is this for a library? Why do you need to know?

Comment: yes, this is for a library. I have tried nothing because I don't know even how to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start with

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary]
```

As @RubberDuck figured out, the key is `UIDeviceFamily`.

1 = iPhone

2 = iPad

Comment: aha!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Now we are talking!!!! It is a nice start. I never imagined the infoDictionary had that much amount of information!!!! fantastic. THANKS!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

As a developer one of your first decisions is to choose which platform to target.

Assuming you are the developer running your app and having compiled it had you chosen Universal you would in code potentially need to determine what platform you are running on - either iPhone or iPad.

When this branching by platform is needed in iOS 7 you implement something similar to:

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
     // The device is an iPad
}
else {
     // The device is an iPhone or iPod touch.
}
```

A mixture of listening for orientation changes in your view controllers and custom views, as well as using multiple Xibs or Storyboards, and checking the Idiom was the norm.

But in iOS 8 Apple is pushing Auto Layout and Size Classes in order to get away from this notion of checking which device you are on. You are on an iOS device. Do you need to do anything different due to the screen size class?

Of course if your App is only targeted to either iPhone or iPad then you need not branch and the user would run it in 2x mode if they are scaling up from iPhone to iPad.

Comment: ok, but the problem with this approach is that this test will fail if you run an iPhone only app on iPad. The test will tell the app that it is running on iPad. Ok, it is running on iPad but because it is an iPhone only app it should report iPhone. I am trying to discover an answer that is not platform dependent.

Comment: You would use the code snippet to determine what device you are running on. If you have an iPhone only app you wouldn't care that you are running on an iPad. You only care if you have a Universal App.